# eclipse plugin to change accessor modifiers for methods and attributes

Tags: java, eclipse

I was wondering if there is any good plugin for eclipse ide, that can change the access modifiers for the properties and methods easily.

Comment: What does accessors mean? is it access modifiers like public/private..?

Comment: Access Modifiers != Accessors. in Java-speak, Accessors are getXyz()-methods, while Mutators are setXyz()-methods

Comment: what do you mean with "change the accessors [...] easily"? Selecting "public" and write "private" is easy!? Or what are you looking for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found this http://accessmodifier.sourceforge.net/